# Rails - Ajax does not refresh correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my app user can mark a product as favorite, and unmark it.

I expect that when a user like a product the icon color changes and that the favorite counter increases with out reloading.

The counter is in the navbar

```
<%= @favorites.count %>
```

Here is the **products/indx.html.erb**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="header_card">
        <%= link_to clients_product_path(product) do  %>
        <div id="like_unlike">
            <% if product.favoriting_users.include? current_user %>
                <% fav = product.favorites.find { |fav| fav.user_id == current_user.id} %>
                <%= link_to clients_product_favorite_path(product, fav), method: :delete , remote: true do %>
                    <i class= "fa fa-heart favorite-active"></i>
                <% end %>       
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to clients_product_favorites_path(product), method: :post, remote: true  do %>
                    <i class= "fa fa-heart not-favorite"></i>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>   
        </div>
        <div id="carousel_<%= product.id%>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
              <% product.attachments.each do |img| %>
              <div class="carousel-item <%= 'active' if img == product.attachments[0] %>">  
                <%= image_tag img.url,  class: "product_suggestion"  %>                                     
              </div>
                <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my **favorites_controller.rb**

```
class Clients::FavoritesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_favorite, only: [:destroy]

    def index
        @favorites = Favorite.where(user: current_user).all
    end

    def create
      @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @user = current_user.id
      favorites = {user_id: @user, product_id: @product.id}
      @favorite = Favorite.new(favorites)

      @favorite.save

        if @favorite.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html {redirect_to clients_products_path(@product)}
          end
        else
            respond_to do | format|
                format.js 
                format.html {redirect_to clients_products_path,  alert: "HOPHOP" }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy 
        if @favorite.destroy!
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js 
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def find_favorite
        find_product
       @favorite = @product.favorites.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

## EDIT

Trying to make the question clearer...

The idea is when a product is liked, the favorites counter `<%= @favorites.count %>` should be incremented with out reloading.
When it's not liked anymore the counter should be decremented

I have two icons, only one is visible according if it is liked or not.

*in my products/index.html.erb I have these lines (complete code above)*

When a product is not yet liked this icon is shown:

```
<%= link_to clients_product_favorites_path(product), method: :post, remote: true  do %>
  <i class= "fa fa-heart not-favorite"></i>
<% end %>
```

When it is liked this icon should appear with out reloading...

```
<% fav = product.favorites.find { |fav| fav.user_id == current_user.id} %>
<%= link_to clients_product_favorite_path(product, fav), method: :delete , remote: true do %>
  <i class= "fa fa-heart favorite-active"></i>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to pass some rails code in the create.js.erb, then the link_to with the method post is changed to the link to with the method delete

**create.js.erb** 
*here I just fake the icon change by changing the css.... it's my hack but I need to retrive the other icon where the delete methode can be used_

```
$('.header_card').bind('.not-favorite').bind('ajax:success', function(){
        $(this).find(".not-favorite").css('color', 'red');
        $("#likes_counter").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
});
```

**destroy.js.erb** 
*same as below*

```
$('.header_card').bind('.favorite-active').bind('ajax:success', function(){
    $("#likes-count").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
    $(this).find(".favorite-active").css('color', 'gray');
});
```

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you're actually having aside from 'Ajax wouldn't work'. Is there a Javascript error before the AJAX is sent or an error from the response? You can check both via Chrome dev tools - JS console for a JS error, or Network tab for a response error (or Rails console will give the response error too)

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest you to simplify your controller like this:

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.create(product: @product) #I guess you have that association already set up

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html {
      if @favorite.persisted?
        redirect_to clients_products_path(@product)
      else
        redirect_to clients_products_path,  alert: "HOPHOP"
      }
  end
end
```

Just to reduce the nomber of lines where things could go wrong.

On the views, you don't have to bind a callback function to the `ajax:success` event, you are already inside that event in the context where that view is being rendered. Just add the lines of code to update the view instead and jquery will execute them.

```
# create.js.erb
$('.header_card .not-favorite').toggleClass('not-favorite').toggleClass('favorite-active');
$("#likes_counter").html("<%= @product.favorites.count %>");

# destroy.js.erb
$('.header_card .favorite-active').toggleClass('not-favorite').toggleClass('favorite-active');
$("#likes-count").html("<%= @product.favorites.count %>");
```

Note the changes on classes (you can set the icon using CSS and then you only need to set the propper class on the button and you are done) and the count (you where using `@favorites` which was not defined on the controller).

Comment: @favorites is defined in application controller because the counter is in the navbar
Color is changing on all icons (I am in an iterration), and the counter isn't incrementing, unless I reload once, and then it increment after each click...

Answer (score 0):

This is what made the job as expected:

I first put my links in div with a #id

```
<div class="like_unlike">
  <% if product.favoriting_users.include? current_user %>
   <div id="unlike_<%= product.id %>">
    <% fav = product.favorites.find { |fav| fav.user_id == current_user.id} %>
      <%= link_to clients_product_favorite_path(product, fav), method: :delete , remote: true do %>
        <i class= "fa fa-heart favorite-active"></i>
    <% end %>   
   </div>   
 <% else %>
    <div id="like_<%= product.id %>">
      <%= link_to clients_product_favorites_path(product), method: :post, remote: true  do %>
        <i class= "fa fa-heart not-favorite"></i>
    <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#header_card_<%= @product.id %>').bind('.not-favorite').bind('ajax:success', function(){

    if("<%= @favorites.count %>" === "1"){
            $("#like_<%= @product.id %>").empty();
            $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %>").find("#like_<%= @product.id %>").replaceWith("<div class='unlike_<%= @product.id %>'><a data-remote='true' rel='nofollow' data-method='delete' href='/clients/products/<%= @product.id %>/favorites/<%= @favorite.id %>'><i class= 'fa fa-heart favorite-active'></i></a></div>"); 
            $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %> .not-favorite").toggleClass('not-favorite').toggleClass('favorite-active');
            $("#likes_counter").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
        location.reload();  
    }
    else {
        $("#like_<%= @product.id %>").empty();
        $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %>").find("#like_<%= @product.id %>").replaceWith("<div class='unlike_<%= @product.id %>'><a data-remote='true' rel='nofollow' data-method='delete' href='/clients/products/<%= @product.id %>/favorites/<%= @favorite.id %>'><i class= 'fa fa-heart favorite-active'></i></a></div>"); 
        $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %> .not-favorite").toggleClass('not-favorite').toggleClass('favorite-active');
        $("#likes_counter").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
    }
});
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#header_card_<%= @product.id %>').bind('.not-favorite').bind('ajax:success', function(){ 
    if('<%= @favorites.count %>' === "0" || "<%= @favorites.first %>"){
        $("#likes_counter").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
      $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %> .favorite-active").toggleClass('favorite-active').toggleClass('not-favorite');
        $("#unlike_<%= @product.id %>").empty();
        $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %>").find("#unlike_<%= @product.id %>").replaceWith("<div class='like_<%= @product.id %>'><a data-remote='true' rel='nofollow' data-method='post' href='/clients/products/<%= @product.id %>/favorites %>'><i class= 'fa fa-heart favorite-active'></i></a></div>");
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        $("#likes_counter").html("<%= @favorites.count %>");
      $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %> .favorite-active").toggleClass('favorite-active').toggleClass('not-favorite');
        $("#unlike_<%= @product.id %>").empty();
        $("#header_card_<%= @product.id %>").find("#unlike_<%= @product.id %>").replaceWith("<div class='like_<%= @product.id %>'><a data-remote='true' rel='nofollow' data-method='post' href='/clients/products/<%= @product.id %>/favorites %>'><i class= 'fa fa-heart favorite-active'></i></a></div>");
    }
});
```